# Ordering of Algorithmic Complexity

Tags: algorithms, computational-complexity

Really just looking to check that my order of algorithmic complexity (based on runtime) is correct. From least to greatest:
$n^{\log(n)} \le n^{4/3} \le n(\log(n))^3 \le 2^{\sqrt{\log(n)}} \le 2^n \le 2^{n^2} \le 2^{2^n}$

Not that it makes a huge difference, but im looking at practical complexity and not theoretical complexity.
I'm basing this entirely off my knowledge of $n^2 \le 2^n$ and $\log(n) \le n$

Answer (score 1):

The first three are wrong. The last three hold (obviously).

[This table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity#Table_of_common_time_complexities) might help you with the first two.